# Update Custom Settings using JavaScript - Salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I have looking everywhere for this kind of problem, but I have found nothing about it. Is there possible to update `custom settings` using just `javascript` code in Salesforce?

Custom Settings can be accessed using:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var url = "{!$Setup.MyCustomSet__c.URL__c}";
    alert(url);
</script>
```

There is solution to pass `javascript` variable to `Apex` and then insert in `custom settings`, but i am looking for direct way of doing that. Any direction would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the solution. Basically its the same as the standard or custom object, just query the API name of custom settings object and set the preferred values.

Here is example of the code:

```
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
var custom_sett_obj = new sforce.SObject("custom_settings_obj__c");
console.log(custom_sett_obj);

custom_sett_obj.Last_Name__c = 'Test';
var result = sforce.connection.create([custom_sett_obj]);

if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) {
    alert("Record " + result[0].id + " created!");
} else {
    alert("failed to create " + result[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom settings are supposed to be relatively static data that can be used to avoid querying their database. Setting one via JS kind of defeats the purpose. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I did not agree with this statement, custom settings can be very good at keeping access tokens that are relative and they are changing over time, so that is the purpose of my question and my issue.

Comment: If it is a user specific token, why not put it in a custom field on the User record instead?

Comment: Its not user specific token, its based on whole organization. Beside, the question was if there is way of saving something in custom settings using javascript.